# Check if there is no GUI

Tags: command-line, gui

Is it possible to check if a UNIX machine (Mac / Linux) has a GUI?

Basically I would like to distinguish between:

- UNIXes with GUI (i.e. normal Macs, Linuxs)
- UNIXes with no GUI (i.e. Mac server/ linux server etc.)

I have tried to use the $DISPLAY variable, but I don't think it works in Mac OS (It doesn't on my Yosemite installation).

---

#### Background

I am writing a (*ruby*) script that starts up a local server on the UNIX machine and then opens this local server in the default browser (using `open http://localhost:4567` or `xdg-open http://localhost:4567` depending on the OS).

The problem is that this script is likely to be used on servers as well as on normal computers (i.e. machines with and without a GUI) and I don't want to annoy users on servers by opening the local server URL in a command line browser (such as lynx etc.).

NB. I plan to check the `$SSH_CLIENT` variable (etc.) before I test for the GUI. Thus, the script will not try to open the default browser if you SSH into a machine. So the above is to target users that physically connect to a server (and not through SSH).

Comment: The $DISPLAY variable does not work on macs because they no longer use X11 : [see here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293)